# OnLoadevent JavaScipt support for Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Our customer is facing some issues to send some Performance Metrics and Health Check from an Azure B2C Journey to the New Relic. They already tried adding a javascript code on a custom B2C Journey, but it did not work because the New Relic Browser Agent do NR cannot intercept the 'on page load' event inside the web view. Wanted to know if this is supported. and if yes, any pointers to troubleshoot this.

Comment: OnLoad event in Javascript is supported. I don't think New Relic is supported for Azure AD B2C user journey Please refer the [document](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/feature-idea-implement-azure-active-directory-b2c-into-azure-infrastructure-integration/93139)

Answer (score 0):

(Moving from comment to answer)

OnLoad event in Javascript is supported. I don't think New Relic is supported for Azure AD B2C user journey Please refer the [document](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/feature-idea-implement-azure-active-directory-b2c-into-azure-infrastructure-integration/93139)